# Area of bounded region question

Tags: geometry, circles

A square ABCD is inscribed in a circle of unit radius. semicircles are described externally on each side with the side as a diameter. the area of region bounded by four semicircle and the circle is

Comment: For all geometry questions a picture is more helpful than a description. Additionally include what you have tried.

Comment: A diagram would help

Comment: this guy explains it here ;-

https://youtu.be/0_mJQ4Y_QMY?t=17m53s

I did not understand the part " the area of region bounded by four semicircle and the circle" . The area of the region he calculated is not bounded by the circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second sentence still misses some words, to make any sense. Using google resulted in:

```
Semicircles are described externally on each side with the side as a diameter.
```

And the following picture was also linked.[image: this]
You could have included such a picture in your question! In your next question also show what you have tried so far. (Also, a non-English video is not really helpful.)

I will give you the tools to solve the problem. Your task is to understand this answer, and do the calculation.

---

The area that should be calculated is the area between the red circle and the blue circles. 
Hence we need to calculate:

- $A_{blue}$, area of *one* blue circle.
- $A_{red}$, area of the red circle.
- $A_{square}$, area of the square.

Then the desired area is given by: 
$$4\cdot\frac{A_{blue}}{2} - (A_{red}-A_{square})$$
The factor 4 is due to the fact that there are 4 blue circles. The factor $\frac{1}{2}$, since we need the semi-circles.

We know that the dashed line, connecting  B and the center, has length 1. 
Hence, we can calculate $A_{red}$.

Using Pythagorean's theorem, you get $\overline{AB}$, and you can calculate $A_{blue}$ and $A_{square}$.

Comment: Ignore my previous question in this comment. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: @user2625361 Uhm, that is exactly what is written in the sentence, that you quoted, isn't it?  The area of the region *bounded* by the four smaller *semi*-circles and the big circle. Have a look at the picture in my answer. It is the only region that is bounded by those circles.

Comment: Yeah, I finally googled the meaning of bounded. I initially though bounded meant overlapping. Sorry, my English is not good. Again thanks for answering my incomplete and gibberish question.